# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on socket.io with https

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following code **server-side**

```
var app = require('express.io')();
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    privateKey : fs.readFileSync(path1).toString(),
    certificate : fs.readFileSync(path2).toString()
};

app.on('connection', function(){});

app.https(options).io();
```

And **client-side**

```
var socket = io('https://url:3000', { "secure": true, 'connect timeout': 5000 });
```

This gives me the following javascript error

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://url:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423002967190-93. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

How can I solve this so that I'm surely using **https**?

Comment: is your problem solved? this is my same problem